# Why do Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel consistently open at login, even though I never asked them to and they are not in my 'Startup Items'

Tags: ms-office, startup

Starting around 2018, Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel consistently launch for me at login, even though I never asked them to and they are not in my 'Startup Items'

I noticed this first around Mac OS Mojave last year and now it is also n MacOS Catalina (even though I *did not* use Migration assistant or upgrade— this Catalina install was a 'clean install' of Catalina, and I still see the same symptom on two separate systems and two separate machines.)

On my Mac last year (Mojave) I noticed Excel always started up whenever I booted up my mac. Now both Excel and Word start up even though they are not in the Startup Items for this user.

MacOS Catalina 10.15.5 with MS Excel 16.16.22 and MS Word 16.16.22

Comment: When you shut down or reboot your Mac it will ask if you want to open all currently open apps the next reboot. Have you seen  that dialog box and is it checked?

Comment: Right, I've seen that. it still happens when I manually quit all programs, reboot without the "Restart apps upon reboot" option checked.

Comment: That's odd. If they're not listed in your user's `Startup Items`, could they be listed in an Admin user's startup? If not, I would look at the Microsoft apps - they may have some way to set themselves to start at login.